# mysql column substring ()

Tags: mysql, substring, substr

In the function below I am implementing substring for the field `$field` but I am getting,

```
Error Notice: Error: Unknown column 'EBook_at' in 'field list'
```

I know there is no column like `EBook_at` but how substring the $field.

Expecting Output:

/image/**56789011**/5678901145678

```
public function prependText($adjustment) {
    $prepend_text = $adjustment[0];     
    $field = $adjustment[1];        
    $this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . "hj_import SET `" . $field . "` = CONCAT( '" . $this->db->escape($prepend_text) . "'," . SUBSTR($field,0,8) . "`, `" . $field . "` )");
}
```

Comment: Dump the contents of the query and take a look at what all that concat and substr is doing before you use it. Without any sample values in your question it's pretty tough to guess at what's going on.

Comment: Considering the three values you are concatenating are all in php variables. I would recommend putting them together in php and not in mysql, it will make the code cleaner and tends to help with little issues like this. It seems you have an inconsistency in your quotes in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed by using below query :

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE ' . DB_PREFIX . "hj_import SET `" . $field . "` = CONCAT( '" . $this->db->escape($prepend_text) . "', substr($field, 1, 8 ),'/',`" . $field . "` )");
```